# Moving or copying single character folders names in windows explorer causes explorer crash

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, copy, runtime-error, move

I have found a very specific bug in Windows in which folders whose names only have a single character cannot be copied/moved. If I have a folder named 'Q', and in explorer attempt to drag copy or move the folder to another location on the drive, explorer will crash and restart. A special case is on an external USB attached drive, where the copy will throw a:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
Runtime Error!
Program:

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

The listed program is indeed empty. The problem does not happen in the command prompt where the move succeeds without issue.

- Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
- 10.0.19045 Build 19045

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode ?

Comment: Having done the experiment, yes it happens under minimal safe mode.

Comment: I can't manage to reproduce this problem at my end. Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Have done both of those in administrator privilege and restarted, issue persists.

Comment: Do you know which process issues the error? If in doubt use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and drag the bullseye icon over the message.

Comment: Brilliant tool. Initially it looked like Tortoise Git might have been the culprit, however on uninstall and restart, the issue persists. The process tree that is now highlighted in Process Explorer is now: `winlogon.exe > explorer.exe`.

Comment: In "Programs and Features", which "Visual C++ Redistributables" do you find?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146563/discussion-between-j-collins-and-harrymc).